# GitLab CI login to private repo without DinD

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm new to GitLab and not sure if this is possible, I have on premise GitLab set up and working as well as Artifactory private repo.

I always used DinD configuration, using Docker as the main image with DinD service, then in the stages logging in and pulling different images from the private repo.

But I heard it's possible to do this without DinD to have shorter execution times. And the needed image is pulled in the beginning of a stage.

Instead of this:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:18.09.8-dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375 

stages:
  - run_script

run_script:
  stage:
    run_script
  script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_TECHNICAL_USER -p $DOCKER_TECHNICAL_USER_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL
    - docker pull artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3
    - docker run -it artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3 pwsh -command "get-process"
```

I want to do it like this(whole yml):

```
stages:
  - run_script

run_script:
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_TECHNICAL_USER -p $DOCKER_TECHNICAL_USER_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL
  image: artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3
  stage:
    run_script
  script:
    - pwsh -command "get-process"
```

If I try this it says it can't authenticate:

```
ERROR: Job failed: image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Get https://artifactory.example.com:5000/v2/repo/powershell-core/manifests/6.3: unknown: Authentication is required
```

Is this impossible or do I have a mistake somewhere and it's fixable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your problem

Your CI is failing because it doesn't know the credentials for `artifactory.example.com` when downloading the base image `artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3`.
For you to understand, I'll explain the different steps of the 2 CIs you gave and then I'll give tracks for a solution.

## First CI (DinD)

In your first CI (the one using DinD), what happens is :

- The Gitlab-runner executor download the image `docker:18.09.8-dind` and then it starts the image as a service for your CI
- The Gitlab-runner executor download the **base image** `docker:latest` and then it uses it to execute your job `run_script`
- In your docker `docker:latest`, the job `run_script` log in your private repository with your credentials and through the DinD service
- Then it download your image `artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3` and run a script using it, all through the DinD service

## Second CI

In this one, you are trying just to execute your image `artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3` and run a script using it.
You are right, for a simple goal like that no DinD is necessary.
Here is the analysis of what your CI is doing :

- The Gitlab-runner executor try to download the **base image** specified by the job `run_script` : `artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3`
- The repository `artifactory.example.com` ask for credentials
- The executor doesn't know any credentials so it returns an error and it stops

As you can see, in this case, the job `run_script` was never executed because **the executor failed to download the base image** specified by the job.
The `before_script` part of the job, which is responsible for the login, is not executed either because **the `before_script` is executed in the base image** and this last one couldn't be downloaded by the executor.

Thus, the solution is simply to give the credentials to the executor so it can login and then download the base image of your job.
Also, the `before_script` part of your job should be removed because it is not executed at the time you intended and therefore not necessary.

## Solution

So what you seek is a way to give the credentials for your repository `artifactory.example.com` to the Gilab-runner executor your job is using.
Sadly, there is no unique way to do such a thing because it depends on the executor that you are using.
Since you didn't specify the executor in your question, I'll give the solutions that, I think, are the most used and convenient for Docker and Kubernetes.

### Using `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`

One solution which works with several executors is to define a (secret) variable directly in Gitlab as explained in [this Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determining-your-docker_auth_config-data).

Here, I present the second method to prepare your credentials. Adapt the following to generate your own `auth` fied :

```sh
echo -n "USERNAME:PASSWORD" | base64
VVNFUk5BTUU6UEFTU1dPUkQ=
```

Then create a variable `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` in Gitlab with the following content that you adapted first :

```
{
  "auths": {
    "artifactory.example.com:5000": {
      "auth": "VVNFUk5BTUU6UEFTU1dPUkQ="
    }
  }
}
```

Using this method, your CI simply becomes :

```
stages:
  - run_script

run_script:
  image: artifactory.example.com:5000/repo/powershell-core:6.3
  stage:
    run_script
  script:
    - pwsh -command "get-process"
```

This solution works for most cases.
However, depending on your executor and the access you have to it, you may want to use other specific solutions.

### Kubernetes executor

If you are using Kubernetes executor, the simplest solution is to create a secret containing the credentials for your repository.
Using the runner's Helm chart, this secret can be given during the chart installation using the `runners.imagePullSecrets` key which is described in the [values.yaml of the chart](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/master/values.yaml).
This solution uses the Kubernetes' mechanism to authenticate into the registry as explained in the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

I give this example to illustrate the fact that the runner's authentication into the registry is using mechanisms that are independent of the runner itself. In this case, it is Kubernetes' mechanisms. Therefore, there is no unique way for the runner to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Really helped to understand this. We are using OpenShift and it has Kubernetes executor. I found that it was already configured but needed some updating.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. I find that the management of CI base images is often a tricky question that needs one's understanding to be really clear on the execution order of CI's steps. Thus, taking the time to dissect the CI helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Bichon Thanks for your wonderful reply. And here is another situation when using kubernetes excutor and dind in your k8s cluster.In my case I my dind service is work nice when I prove it by exec into the pod.But there still error in my runner(k8s excutor with "docker:stable" image),though I've config DOCKER_HOST and make the client pointer to the dind pod.

I been search a lot of place and they didn't mention that case,and I just **sovle it by docker login again in my runner script** details are in there:https://forum.gitlab.com/t/insecure-docker-registry-kubernetes-runner/51271/2?u=lzd-1230

Though I fix this by numerous tring,*but I still confused about it*... because I thought it is unnecessary because the server is in dind and it has been well config!!